# Unexpectedly long delay in executing a function wrapped in AngularJS's $timeout service

Tags: angularjs

I have a really strange problem with AngularJS's $timeout service, but let's start from the beginning.

I have a web application that should ping the server each 3 seconds (more or less). So, I'm using the $timeout service, in order to send the "/ping" request, in the following way:

```
angular.module(…)
.factory('ping', ['$http', '$timeout', 'auth', function ($http, $timeout, auth) {
    return {
        init: function () {
            (function sendPing() {
                var pingInterval = 3000;

                if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $http
                        .post('/ping')
                        .success(function () {
                            $timeout(sendPing, pingInterval);
                        })
                        .error(function () {
                            $timeout(sendPing, pingInterval);
                        });
                } else {
                    $timeout(sendPing, pingInterval);
                }
            })();
        }
    };
}])
.run([ 'ping', … , function (ping, …) {
    //…
    ping.init();
    //…
}]);
```

And it generally works. However I encontered very strange behavior lately - it seems that sometimes (rarely) the interval, between sending the "/ping" requests, increases from 3 seconds to even 2 minutes. The web application has many clients (they use Chrome) but for most of them the issue doesn't happen. Unfortunately, I don't have an access to the "troublesome" clients' workstations (virtual machines) so it's hard to tell if there's a problem with the long DOM loading or something else. However, they haven't reported any UI issues.

The IIS server logs show that the "/ping" requests, from those clients, didn't even reach the server. At the beginning, I thought this might be related to Chrome's "Background Tabs Throttling" feature, but as far as I know the clients keep the tab (with open web application) active. I know that it would be good to log some additional data for the "sendPing()" function but I can't do it right now (all production deployments are stopped because of the company's policy).

- AngularJS version: 1.0.7
- Chrome version: 68.0.3

**The question:** Is it even possible that it's AngularJS issue? If so, what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You are creating a new instance of `$timeout` each time you call the `sendPing` function. Hence your app goes nuts. You should divide concerns: e.g. have two functions: `sendPing` and `createPingTimeout`